# How to export Google analytics data without a view id

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-analytics-4

For the last 2-3 days i am trying to somehow download the "Pages and screens: Page path and screen class" reports so i can include the data on my management system,

I tried to use the Google Analytics API in PHP, here is an example

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$profileId = ''; // But i cant get the profile id because the Analytics account doesnt have them

$yesterday = $startDate = $endDate = date("Y-m-d", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);

$metrics = 'sessions';

$results = $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId, $startDate, $endDate, 'ga:' . $metrics);
print_r($results);
```

But as mentioned in the code my Google Analytics account doesn't have Views

[image: Screenshot from the Analytics Tab]

[image: Basicly what i want to archive]

Here again summarized i need a way to download the report seen as in the picture automatically, it could be in any language (ex PHP, Python, Java etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Reporting API that works only for Universal Analytics Property. In your case you are trying to get info from the new Google Analytics 4 Property, not Universal Analytics. So you have to use the Google Analytics Data API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

Comment: I figured it out, Thanks for putting me on the right path